# Stream melt framework video with VLC - no sout stream modules matched 

Tags: vlc, melt-framework

I followed the two example commands based on [How can I stream as transport stream over HTTP?](https://www.mltframework.org/faq/#how-can-i-stream-as-transport-stream-over-http)  only changing the url, I am attempting it do this inside fresh debian docker container with only apt vlc and melt framework, so it shouldnt be a network issue.

I will be forever in your debt if you can help!

Using this first to start the stream, where there is melt formatted xml, the project renders with this normally.
`melt -profile square_pal project.xml -consumer avformat:udp://224.224.224.224:1234?pkt_size=1316\&reuse=1 real_time=1 terminate_on_pause=0 f=mpegts vcodec=mpeg4 b=1000k s=320x240 acodec=mp2 ab=128k`

[image]

Then using the following in a a seperate terminal:

`cvlc -I dummy -vvv udp://@224.224.224.224:1234 --sout \#std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=0.0.0.0:8081}`
[image]

Warning full output

```
vlc@f56c133a87c5:/usr$ cvlc -I dummy -vv udp://@0.0.0.0:1234 --sout \#std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=0.0.0.0:8081}
VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)
[000056517c3bf460] main libvlc debug: VLC media player - 3.0.16 Vetinari
[000056517c3bf460] main libvlc debug: Copyright © 1996-2021 the VideoLAN team
[000056517c3bf460] main libvlc debug: revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2
[000056517c3bf460] main libvlc debug: configured with ./configure  '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--prefix=/usr' '--includedir=${prefix}/include' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--disable-option-checking' '--disable-silent-rules' '--libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--runstatedir=/run' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--disable-debug' '--config-cache' '--disable-update-check' '--enable-fast-install' '--docdir=/usr/share/doc/vlc' '--with-binary-version=3.0.16-1' '--enable-a52' '--enable-aa' '--enable-aribsub' '--enable-avahi' '--enable-bluray' '--enable-caca' '--enable-chromaprint' '--enable-chromecast' '--enable-dav1d' '--enable-dbus' '--enable-dca' '--enable-dvbpsi' '--enable-dvdnav' '--enable-faad' '--enable-flac' '--enable-fluidsynth' '--enable-freetype' '--enable-fribidi' '--enable-gles2' '--enable-gnutls' '--enable-harfbuzz' '--enable-jack' '--enable-kate' '--enable-libass' '--enable-libmpeg2' '--enable-libxml2' '--enable-lirc' '--enable-mad' '--enable-matroska' '--enable-mod' '--enable-mpc' '--enable-mpg123' '--enable-mtp' '--enable-ncurses' '--enable-notify' '--enable-ogg' '--enable-opus' '--enable-pulse' '--enable-qt' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-samplerate' '--enable-sdl-image' '--enable-sftp' '--enable-shine' '--enable-shout' '--enable-skins2' '--enable-sndio' '--enable-soxr' '--enable-spatialaudio' '--enable-speex' '--enable-svg' '--enable-svgdec' '--enable-taglib' '--enable-theora' '--enable-twolame' '--enable-upnp' '--enable-vdpau' '--enable-vnc' '--enable-vorbis' '--enable-x264' '--enable-x265' '--enable-zvbi' '--with-kde-solid=/usr/share/solid/actions/' '--disable-aom' '--disable-crystalhd' '--disable-d3d11va' '--disable-decklink' '--disable-directx' '--disable-dsm' '--disable-dxva2' '--disable-fdkaac' '--disable-fluidlite' '--disable-freerdp' '--disable-goom' '--disable-gst-decode' '--disable-libtar' '--disable-live555' '--disable-macosx' '--disable-macosx-avfoundation' '--disable-macosx-qtkit' '--disable-mfx' '--disable-microdns' '--disable-opencv' '--disable-projectm' '--disable-schroedinger' '--disable-sparkle' '--disable-srt' '--disable-telx' '--disable-vpx' '--disable-vsxu' '--disable-wasapi' '--enable-alsa' '--enable-dc1394' '--enable-dv1394' '--enable-libplacebo' '--enable-linsys' '--enable-nfs' '--enable-udev' '--enable-v4l2' '--enable-wayland' '--enable-libva' '--enable-vcd' '--enable-smbclient' '--disable-oss' '--enable-mmx' '--enable-sse' '--disable-neon' '--disable-altivec' '--disable-omxil' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/vlc-0rjD9V/vlc-3.0.16=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/vlc-0rjD9V/vlc-3.0.16=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' 'OBJCFLAGS=-g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/vlc-0rjD9V/vlc-3.0.16=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security'
[000056517c3bf460] main libvlc debug: searching plug-in modules
[000056517c3bf460] main libvlc debug: loading plugins cache file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
[000056517c3bf460] main libvlc debug: recursively browsing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/plugins'
[000056517c3bf460] main libvlc debug: plug-ins loaded: 508 modules
[000056517c3bf460] main libvlc debug: opening config file (/home/vlc/.config/vlc/vlcrc)
[000056517c3bf7b0] main logger debug: looking for logger module matching "any": 4 candidates
[000056517c3bf7b0] main logger debug: using logger module "console"
[000056517c3bf460] main libvlc debug: translation test: code is "C"
[000056517c457300] main keystore debug: looking for keystore module matching "memory": 4 candidates
[000056517c457300] main keystore debug: using keystore module "memory"
[000056517c3bf460] main libvlc debug: CPU has capabilities MMX MMXEXT SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FPU
[000056517c45b910] main input debug: Creating an input for 'Media Library'
[000056517c45b910] main input debug: Input is a meta file: disabling unneeded options
[000056517c45b910] main input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
[000056517c45b910] main input debug: using default timeshift path
[000056517c45b910] main input debug: `file/directory:///home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' gives access `file' demux `directory' path `/home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[000056517c456b60] main input source debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='directory' location='/home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[000056517c455620] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module matching "file": 16 candidates
[000056517c455620] main demux debug: no access_demux modules matched
[000056517c47af40] main stream debug: creating access: file:///home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf
[000056517c47af40] main stream debug:  (path: /home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf)
[000056517c47af40] main stream debug: looking for access module matching "file": 28 candidates
[000056517c47af40] main stream debug: using access module "filesystem"
[000056517c47c330] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "prefetch,cache_read": 26 candidates
[000056517c47c330] cache_read stream debug: Using stream method for AStream*
[000056517c47c330] cache_read stream debug: starting pre-buffering
[000056517c47c330] cache_read stream debug: received first data after 0 ms
[000056517c47c330] cache_read stream debug: pre-buffering done 296 bytes in 0s - 5781 KiB/s
[000056517c47c330] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "cache_read"
[000056517c47d390] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 26 candidates
[000056517c47d390] playlist stream debug: using XSPF playlist reader
[000056517c47d390] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "playlist"
[000056517c47d390] main stream debug: stream filter added to 0x56517c47c330
[000056517c480890] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 26 candidates
[000056517c480890] main stream debug: no stream_filter modules matched
[000056517c456910] main stream_directory debug: looking for stream_directory module matching "any": 1 candidates
[000056517c456910] main stream_directory debug: no stream_directory modules matched
[000056517c456b60] main input source debug: attachment of directory-extractor failed for file:///home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf
[000056517c480890] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "record": 26 candidates
[000056517c480890] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "record"
[000056517c456b60] main input source debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='directory' location='/home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[000056517c455620] main demux debug: looking for demux module matching "directory": 54 candidates
[000056517c455620] main demux debug: using demux module "directory"
[000056517c484760] main demux meta debug: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
[000056517c484760] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[000056517c484760] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[000056517c484760] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/reader/filename.luac
[000056517c484760] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[000056517c484760] main demux meta debug: no meta reader modules matched
[000056517c45b910] main input debug: `file/directory:///home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' successfully opened
[000056517c489570] main xml reader debug: looking for xml reader module matching "any": 1 candidates
[000056517c489570] main xml reader debug: using xml reader module "xml"
[000056517c45b910] main input debug: EOF reached
[000056517c455620] main demux debug: removing module "directory"
[000056517c480890] main stream debug: removing module "record"
[000056517c47d390] main stream debug: removing module "playlist"
[000056517c47c330] main stream debug: removing module "cache_read"
[000056517c47af40] main stream debug: removing module "filesystem"
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: creating audio output
[000056517c4803d0] main audio output debug: looking for audio output module matching "any": 6 candidates
[000056517c4803d0] vlcpulse audio output debug: using library version 14.2.0
[000056517c4803d0] vlcpulse audio output debug:  (compiled with version 14.2.0, protocol 34)
[000056517c4803d0] vlcpulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
[000056517c4803d0] alsa audio output debug: Available ALSA PCM devices:
[000056517c4803d0] alsa audio output debug: Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture) (null)
[000056517c4803d0] main audio output debug: using audio output module "alsa"
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: keeping audio output
[000056517c4c4230] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "dbus,none": 17 candidates
[000056517c4c4230] dbus interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
[000056517c4c4230] main interface debug: no interface modules matched
[000056517c4c4230] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[000056517c3bf460] main libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization failed
[000056517c4c4230] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "hotkeys,none": 17 candidates
[00007f975c000c20] main input debug: Creating an input for preparsing '#stddst=0.0.0.0:8081'
[000056517c4c4230] main interface debug: using interface module "hotkeys"
[000056517c493b30] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "globalhotkeys,none": 17 candidates
[00007f975c000c20] main input debug: Creating an input for preparsing '#stdmux=ts'
[000056517c493b30] main interface debug: no interface modules matched
[000056517c493b30] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[000056517c3bf460] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[000056517c493b30] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "dummy": 17 candidates
[00007f9750000c20] main meta fetcher debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
[00007f9750000c20] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[00007f9750000c20] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[00007f9750000c20] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[000056517c493b30] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[000056517c493b30] main interface debug: using interface module "dummy"
[00007f9750000c20] main meta fetcher debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
[00007f9750000c20] main art finder debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: processing request item: null, node: Playlist, skip: 0
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: rebuild done - 3 items, index -1
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: starting playback of new item
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: resyncing on udp://0.0.0.0:1234
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: udp://0.0.0.0:1234 is at 0
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: creating new input thread
[00007f9748000c80] main input debug: Creating an input for 'udp://0.0.0.0:1234'
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: requesting art for new input thread
[00007f9758000e60] main stream output debug: using sout chain=`stdaccess=http'
[00007f9758000e60] main stream output debug: stream=`stdaccess=http'
[00007f97580010e0] main stream out debug: looking for sout stream module matching "stdaccess=http": 23 candidates
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
[00007f97580010e0] main stream out debug: no sout stream modules matched
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
[00007f97580010e0] main stream out debug: destroying chain... (name=(null))
[00007f97580010e0] main stream out debug: destroying chain done
[00007f9758000e60] main stream output error: stream chain failed for `stdaccess=http'
[00007f9748000c80] main input error: cannot start stream output instance, aborting
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: dead input
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f9750000c20] main art finder debug: no art finder modules matched
[00007f9750000c20] main meta fetcher debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
[00007f9750000c20] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[00007f9750000c20] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[00007f9750000c20] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[00007f9750000c20] main meta fetcher debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
[00007f9750000c20] main art finder debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f9750000c20] main art finder debug: no art finder modules matched
[00007f9750000c20] main meta fetcher debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
[00007f9750000c20] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[00007f9750000c20] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[00007f9750000c20] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[00007f9750000c20] main meta fetcher debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
[00007f9750000c20] main art finder debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f9750000c20] main art finder debug: no art finder modules matched
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: changing item without a request (current 0/3)
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: using item 1
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: starting playback of new item
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: resyncing on #stdmux=ts
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: #stdmux=ts is at 1
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: creating new input thread
[00007f9748000c80] main input debug: Creating an input for '#stdmux=ts'
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: requesting art for new input thread
[00007f9750001630] main stream output debug: using sout chain=`stdaccess=http'
[00007f9750001630] main stream output debug: stream=`stdaccess=http'
[00007f97500017c0] main stream out debug: looking for sout stream module matching "stdaccess=http": 23 candidates
[00007f97500017c0] main stream out debug: no sout stream modules matched
[00007f97500017c0] main stream out debug: destroying chain... (name=(null))
[00007f97500017c0] main stream out debug: destroying chain done
[00007f9750001630] main stream output error: stream chain failed for `stdaccess=http'
[00007f9748000c80] main input error: cannot start stream output instance, aborting
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: dead input
[00007f9750000c20] main meta fetcher debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
[00007f9750000c20] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[00007f9750000c20] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[00007f9750000c20] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[00007f9750000c20] main meta fetcher debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
[00007f9750000c20] main art finder debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f9750000c20] main art finder debug: no art finder modules matched
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: changing item without a request (current 1/3)
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: using item 2
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: starting playback of new item
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: resyncing on #stddst=0.0.0.0:8081
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: #stddst=0.0.0.0:8081 is at 2
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: creating new input thread
[00007f9748000c80] main input debug: Creating an input for '#stddst=0.0.0.0:8081'
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: requesting art for new input thread
[00007f9750001630] main stream output debug: using sout chain=`stdaccess=http'
[00007f9750001630] main stream output debug: stream=`stdaccess=http'
[00007f97500017c0] main stream out debug: looking for sout stream module matching "stdaccess=http": 23 candidates
[00007f97500017c0] main stream out debug: no sout stream modules matched
[00007f97500017c0] main stream out debug: destroying chain... (name=(null))
[00007f97500017c0] main stream out debug: destroying chain done
[00007f9750001630] main stream output error: stream chain failed for `stdaccess=http'
[00007f9748000c80] main input error: cannot start stream output instance, aborting
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: dead input
[00007f9750000c20] main meta fetcher debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
[00007f9750000c20] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[00007f9750000c20] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[00007f9750000c20] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[00007f9750000c20] main meta fetcher debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
[00007f9750000c20] main art finder debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/vlc/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
[00007f9750000c20] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f9750000c20] main art finder debug: no art finder modules matched
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: changing item without a request (current 2/3)
[000056517c3c0e50] main playlist debug: nothing to play
```

Seems like a VLC issue, even running vlc normally causes some errors, wondering how I can fix it.

Comment: Why did you change `224.224.224.224` to `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: @Nearoo thanks for replying, I wanted to expose the path to localhost, so i used 0.0.0.0, and hoping I can access it using host.docker.internal from the frontend. I tried using 224.224.224.224 as well, no difference though

Comment: Just in case I checked again with both commands inside the docker container using 224.224.224.224:1234 but no luck unfortunately.